# Property 'imageLoader' not found on object of type 'RCTBridge *'

Tags: react-native

I have updated my iPad to latest version of iOS, then updated XCode, and it required me to update my react-native package.json, so i did.
Now i got bunch of errors i don't understand how to fix, like that:

`Property 'imageLoader' not found on object of type 'RCTBridge *'`

Here is my project's dependencies, i'm pretty sure the problem is caused by react-native-image-crop-picker

`"react-native": "^0.61.1"`

`"react-native-image-crop-picker": ">= 0.25.0"`

Did anyone face same issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot?

Comment: @Iva updated post

Comment: did you updated pod file for the same project as well if not try to update that file,that might help.

Comment: @Iva yep, i did, now reupdated, same error :(

Comment: did you use react-native-map in your project?

Comment: @BadriDerakhshan nope

Comment: i had some problem like this when i upgrade react-native to new version,and i had to create new react-native project

Comment: @BadriDerakhshan yeah probably i should have to start from scratch and make it much better, but it is not the case for now.